# Get serial number from banner using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to grab the serial number from a Banner. I have successfully done it by storing the banner content in a file, but now I would like to try without storing it in a file. Below is the snippet of code:

```
import argparse
import logging
import paramiko

def grab_banner(ip_address, port):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        client.connect(ip_address, port=port, username='username', password='bad-password-on-purpose')
    except:
        return client._transport.get_banner()
def GetSerialNo(ip_address,Banner):
    fp1=open("Baner","w")
    fp1.write(Banner)
    fp1.close()
    fp2=open("Baner","r")
    for line in fp2:
        if re.search("System S/N", line):
            Serial = line.split()
        return Serial[2]
    fp2.close() 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a demo script')
    parser.add_argument('-s','--ipsetups', help='IP Address')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    Setup_File=args.ipsetups
    fp=open(Setup_File,"r")
    for line in fp.readlines():
        IP = line.strip()
        logger.info("================================  WORKING on %s  ===================================",IP)
        Banner = grab_banner(IP, 22)
        serial = GetSerialNo(IP, Banner)
    logger.info("Serial Number is -> %s",serial)
    fp.close()
```

The above code is working fine, but now I am trying to do it by storing it in some variable and then grabbing the serial number. But I'm unable to do so. Below is what I am trying to do:

```
def get_ip(Setup_File):
   IPS = []
   with open(Setup_File, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       IPS  = line.split()
       return IPS

def grab_banner(ip_address, port):
   client = paramiko.SSHClient()
   client.load_system_host_keys()
   client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   try:
      client.connect(ip_address, port=port, username='username', password='bad-password-on-purpose')
   except:
   return client._transport.get_banner()

if __name__ == '__main__':

 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a demo script by Mangesh Pardhi.')
 parser.add_argument('-s','--ipsetups', help='PD-Setup IP Address')
 args = parser.parse_args()
 Setup_File=args.ipsetups
 print Setup_File
 IPS = get_ip(Setup_File)
 for IP in IPS:
logger.info("================================  WORKING on %s  ===================================",IP)
    Banner = grab_banner(IP, 22)
if "System S/N" in Banner:
    XXXXXXXXXXHow To procees XXXXXXXXXXx
    serial = Serial[2]
logger.info("Serial Number is -> %s",serial)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simplify `GetSerialNo` in your original code.

```
    def GetSerialNo(ip_address, Banner):
        for line in Banner.split('\n'):
            if re.search("System S/N", line):
                Serial = line.split()
                return Serial[2]
```

(Surely you already know that you don't need the parameter `ip_address` there.)